# Get property from php object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I did a var dump of a php object `$grid`, and there is this property that I need to access:

```
["wpupg_post_types"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "a:1:{i:0;s:4:"post";}" }
```

I need to get the word "post" out of that. I tried doing

```
$posttype = $grid->wpupg_post_types;
if (in_array("post", $posttype)) {
 echo "post";
}
```

But that didn't work. And if I try
`var_dump($grid->wpupg_post_types);` it returns NULL.

Do you know how I can do it?

Comment: can you print all $grid variable?

Comment: Sure! Just updated my question.

Comment: UHm too long and bad to read, try to remove many parts to view only the single problem of your object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is an array of strings that are serialized:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"post";}
```

Pull the first item off and then pass it to [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to turn it into an array:

```
$result = unserialize(array_shift($grid->wpupg_post_types));
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => post
)
```

Note: This assumes the property is public.

Comment: Thank you. When I try this, I get no return. When I try var_dump($result), it gives me bool(false). Do you know why that is?

Comment: Is wpupg_post_types public?

Comment: That must be the problem. I don't think it is.

Comment: The class probably has some getter method like `get_post_types()` or something that you can call to get the value.

Comment: Ah ha! I checked out the class, and found `$grid->post_types`. I don't understand why since post_types isn't a property? But nevertheless, this worked: `if( in_array( 'post', $grid->post_types() ) )`

Answer (score 2):

`$posttype = $grid->wpupg_post_types;` contains an array of one element with a serialized array with post.

```
php > $array = [serialize(['post'])];
php > var_dump($array);
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(21) "a:1:{i:0;s:4:"post";}"
}
```

To check if the post is inside the array you need to do another kind of check

```
php > var_dump(in_array('post', unserialize($array[0])));
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
```

Your particular case should be

```
if(in_array('post', unserialize($grid->wpupg_post_types[0]))) {
    echo 'post';
}
```

---

EDIT: here my interactive shell

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $array = [serialize(['post'])];
php > var_dump($array);
php shell code:1:
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(21) "a:1:{i:0;s:4:"post";}"
}
php > var_dump(in_array('post', unserialize($array[0])));
php shell code:1:
bool(true)
php >
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't seem to get it to work. If I try $result = unserialize($grid->wpupg_post_types[0]) and then do a var_dump on $result... it says bool(false).

Comment: An upvote for your time spent on this. Thank you! I found a solution (see my comment to Alex Howansky).